# C# type name does not exist in the type. Public method doesn't appear to be visible

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm new to C# and for my first project I'm attempting to automate some tasks using a web interface.

My understanding of public classes and methods in C# is they should be visible to the rest of the project I'm working on, but that doesn't appear to be the case in this instance.

I get an error "The type name 'ClearAllUnraisedAlerts' does not exist in the type 'ClearAlerts'" and I hope someone can tell me what false assumption or newbie error I'm making here.

My Program.cs is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ManagedWorkspaceAutomator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AutomationFunctions.AlertsBoard.ClearAlerts test = new AutomationFunctions.AlertsBoard.ClearAlerts.ClearAllUnraisedAlerts();
        }
    }
}
```

Which tries to call the ClearAllUnraisedAlerts method in AutomationFunctions\AlertsBoard\ClearAlerts.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace ManagedWorkspaceAutomator.AutomationFunctions.AlertsBoard
{
    public class ClearAlerts
    {
        private IWebDriver _driver;

        public void ClearAllUnraisedAlerts()
        {
            _driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver();

            PageModels.LoginPage login = new PageModels.LoginPage(_driver);

            login.EnterUsername = "testuser";
            login.EnterPassword = "testpass";
            login.ClickLogin();

        }
    }
}
```

For completeness, this is my pagemodel, in PageModels\LoginPage.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace ManagedWorkspaceAutomator.PageModels
{
    public class LoginPage
    {
        protected readonly IWebDriver WebDriver;

        public LoginPage(IWebDriver webdriver)
        {
            this.WebDriver = webdriver;
            string title = WebDriver.Title;

            if(!title.Equals("Managed Workspace Login"))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("This is not the Login Page. Current page is: " + title);
            }

        }

        /*
          A property to enter username on login page
        */
        public string EnterUsername
        {
            set
            {
                IWebElement usernameField = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("txbUserName"));
                usernameField.Clear();
                usernameField.SendKeys(value);
            }
        }

        /*
          A property to enter password on login page
        */

        public string EnterPassword
        {
            set
            {
                IWebElement passwordField = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("txbPassword"));
                passwordField.Clear();
                passwordField.SendKeys(value);
            }
        }

        /*
          A method to click the login button on the page 
        */

        public void ClickLogin()
        {
            IWebElement loginButton = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("SubmitB"));
            loginButton.Click();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you initialize the object is wrong. Please do this

```
AutomationFunctions.AlertsBoard.ClearAlerts test = new ManagedWorkspaceAutomator.AutomationFunctions.AlertsBoard.ClearAlerts();
test.ClearAllUnraisedAlerts();
```

Comment: Ahh I see. I need to initialise the class and then run the class's method. It makes a lot of sense now I think about it.